# jQuery - hide/show footer navigation by cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is have a small navigation menu at the bottom of the window that only displays when the cursor position is near the bottom. I'm able to get it to show, but not hide again. I've tried `mouseleave`, `mouseout` and an `if`, but can't quite get it to work. Here's what I have until I get stuck:

```js
 $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   var cursorPosition = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 60;

   if (cursorPosition >= windowHeight) {
     $('#thumbnail-nav').animate({
       bottom: '-20px'
     }, 500);
   }
 });
```

```css
#thumbnail-nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 110px;
  bottom: -150px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 25%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
#thumbnail-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="thumbnail-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/jkewcaab/)**.

Could someone give me a little direction on this?

Comment: You need to do something when the cursor position is lower than the window's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it even better with CSS only:

```css
#thumb-nav-hldr{
    display: block;
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
 height:130px;
 bottom:-130px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;    
}
#thumb-nav-hldr:hover{
    padding-top: 0;
    bottom:0px;
}
#thumbnail-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:110px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 width:50%;
 left:calc(50% - 25%);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
 }
 #thumbnail-nav li {
  display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-flex:1;
        -ms-flex:1;
        flex:1;
  }
```

```html
<div id='thumb-nav-hldr'>
    <ul id="thumbnail-nav">
     <li><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: That's excellent, I didn't even think of going about it that way. I always prefer pure CSS solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with that kind of problems but i think that i found a little solution that can help you.

The solution is using a `boolean variable (flag)`. When it shows the navigation menu you change the value to `true`, and when you leave it, you change it to `false`.

Here is your code with the changes:

```
var showNavMenu = false; // The flag variable set to false because menu is hidden

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var cursorPosition = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 60;

        if(cursorPosition >= 232){

            if (flag === false) { 
                flag = true;
                $('#thumbnail-nav').animate({bottom:'-20px'},500);
            }

        } else {

            if (flag === true) {
                $('#thumbnail-nav').animate({bottom:'-150px'},500);
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

The `if statements` checks the value of the `flag` to show/hide the nav menu.

Comment: That worked, so I upvoted your answer, but I have to go with the pure CSS answer given by @AlexanderDayan